# javascript: new date, missing year

Tags: javascript

I called new Date("Jan 4")
and found the default year is 2001

```
a=new Date("Jan 4")
Thu Jan 04 2001 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

Is there any way that I can set the default year to be 2011?

---

update:
I know that I can use + 2011
but since I have some "Jan 4", and some "Jan 4, 2008"
I only want to use 2011 for the former case.

However, I realize that if you do Date("Jan 4, 2008 2011") the year will be 2008 but not 2011. That's just what I need.
I will mark the first answer correct anyway.

Comment: Never encountered this before. Does anyone know if it is normal behavior and is it consistent across browsers?

Comment: Not to be snide, but why not just `a=new Date("Jan 4 2011")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try :

```
year = new Date().getFullYear(); // current year
a=new Date("Jan 4"+' '+year);
```

Update

You can split the string using

```
'Jan 4, 2008'.split(',')[0]+' '+year;
'Jan 4'.split(',')[0]+' '+year; // still works
```

Comment: ya, that an alternative way as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is truly bizarre behavior.  It seems to be specific to Chrome.  Firefox returns an invalid date.  I guess 2001 will be cool forever.

Comment: Yep, totally correct, Chrome shows 2001 and Firefox shows undefined NaN for me.